# java pattern matcher syntax, selectively incapable of string recognition

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am using the the java pattern matcher to tease out strings of the form 'XXX'('XXX','XXX'). I wan't only the text, i.e. XXX

This is what I'm currently using:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)','(.*?)'\\)\\.");
```

It it's able to match this:

```
'prevents'('scurvy','vitamin C').
'contains'('vitamin C','orange').
'contains'('vitamin C','sauerkraut').
'isa'('fruit','orange').
'improves'('health','fruit').
```

But is incapable to recognizing this, although they are formatted in the same way.

```
'take place in'('the grand hall of the hong kong convention', 'the ceremony').
'attend by'('some # guests', 'the grand hall of the hong kong convention').
'seat on'('the central dais', 'principal representatives of both countries').
'be'('mr jiang', 'representing china').
'be'('hrh', 'britain').
'be more than'('# distinguished guests', 'the principal representatives').
'end with'('the playing of the british national anthem', 'hong kong').
'follow at'('the stroke of midnight', 'this').
'take part in'('the ceremony', 'both countries').
'start at about'('# pm', 'the ceremony').
'end about'('# am', 'the ceremony').
'lower'('the british hong kong flag', '# royal hong kong police officers').
'raise'('the sar flag', 'another #').
'leave for'('the royal yacht britannia', 'the #').
'hold by'('the chinese and british governments', 'the handover of hong kong').
'rise over'('this land', 'the regional flag of the hong kong special administrative region of the people \'s republic of china').
'cast eye on'('hong kong', 'the world').
'hold on'('schedule', 'the # governments').
'be festival for'('the chinese nation', 'this').
'go in'('the annals of history', 'july # , #').
'become master of'('this chinese land', 'the hong kong compatriots').
'enter era of'('development', 'hong kong').
'remember'('mr deng xiaoping', 'history').
'be along'('the course', 'it').
'resolve'('the hong kong question', 'we').
```

What is the cause of this?

Is there a website where I can demo my regex specifically as it is applied to the java pattern matcher? like regexr.com
Or some simple comprehensible documentation would also be good, the results of my google search were highly fragmentary and incoherent.

Comment: I would recommend that you learn about possessive matchers and negated character groups - I suspect your pattern will be rather slow for non-matching text.

Comment: You could test your regex online for example here http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because all has a space after the comma.

So i suggest you to use `\s*` (*matches zero or more spaces*) or `\s?` (*matches an optional space*),

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'\\('(.*?)',\\s*'(.*?)'\\)\\.");
```

Example:

```
 'prevents'('scurvy','vitamin C').
                     ^
                     | - no space
```

But

```
'take place in'('the grand hall of the hong kong convention', 'the ceremony').
                                                             ^
                                                             |- space
```

[DEMO](https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/19)

Comment: AH! haha damn. eagle eye!! should be a double \\ before the s up there.

Comment: oh, i forget to double escape `\s`

Comment: @flavius_valens reference material for what? Regex syntax?

Comment: @flavius_valens http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is the best site for learning regexes..